# Open Liberty inside Eclipse: publishing results in an JMX connection error

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere-liberty, open-liberty, microprofile

I configured the Open Liberty server inside Eclipse 2020-03 using the Eclipse Developer Tools from https://openliberty.io/downloads/#eclipse_developer_tools.

I can add my .war project and start the server without problem, but publishing on the running server results in an Error:
[image]

Also at startup there is an error in the server console:

```
[ERROR   ] CWWKF0001E: A feature definition could not be found for localconnector-1.0
```

that could match this (resolved) discussion on the open-liberty github: https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/6533.

Inside the server.xml Eclipse displays an warning, that the localConnector-1.0 feature is not recognized, but when I try to remove it, it reapears again after saving.

I tried switching between the AdoptJDK 8, 11 and 14 but the behavior does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The localConnector-1.0 feature is required by the tools in order to connect to the server. If it is not there you will get that error message about the JMX connection failure and the tools will keep trying to add it back to the server.xml. Are you using a minimized server with only a specific subset of features? You could install the localConnector-1.0 feature using the installUtility that comes with Liberty. It is found in the bin directory:

```
bin/installUtility install localConnector-1.0
```

You can also install features using the tools. Open the Runtime Explorer view, right click on the Liberty runtime and select **Install Additional Content**. Use the search field to search for local connector, click **Install** for the feature and then finish the wizard, accepting any licenses.

Comment: I used the microProfile3 version of server. After switching to the full version everything works as expected. Thanks.